# Trying to start a SignalR connection from an ASP.NET Core action call gives TypeLoadException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr.client

The setup I'm trying to accomplish is this: I have a signalR server that supports 2 types of clients - one type that supplies data and another that receives data. When a "receiver" type client chooses one of the "sender" type clients to monitor, the SignalR server makes a call to the "sender" client to open a connection. The "sender" client is an ASP.NET Core instance running as a Windows Service. The POST request calls a service that starts a timer and tries to open a SignalR connection as a client. The POST request is going through as expected and it calls the service properly. When the service tries to open the SignalR connection, though, I get: System.TypeLoadException in SignalR.Client.dll (Inheritance security rules violated by type: 'System.Net.Http.WebRequestHandler'. Derived types must either match the security accessibility of the base type or be less accessible).

The action method in the controller looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult StartUpdate()
{
    _updateDriver.StartTiming();

    return Ok("Timing has started");
}
```

And the method in the service looks like this:

```
public void StartTiming()
{
    if (!_isTiming)
    {
        try
        {
            _hubProxy = _hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("RemoteDataServerHub");
            _hubConnection.Start().Wait();
            _hubProxy.Invoke("JoinGroup", "Sender").Wait();
            _timer.Start();
            _isTiming = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Print(ex.Message);
            _isTiming = false;
        }
    }
}
```

The exception is thrown on the _hubConnection.Start().Wait() line. Does anyone have any idea what's going on here? I'm not very experienced in web applications or ASP.NET Core or SignalR. I may be biting off a bit more than I can chew here. But if anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure SignalR for ASP.NET Core is ready for prime time just yet. Here's a blog post from a SingalR developer talking about the new SignalR (ASP.NET Core Sockets) https://blog.3d-logic.com/2017/01/15/signalr-core-part-13-design-considerations/. He has some samples here https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/tree/dev/samples/SocialWeather. And you can watch a talk on it all here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wIsync6vTfQ&t=2808s.

Comment: Thanks! I've had to move on from this a bit but I will be revisiting it shortly. I know SignalR in ASP.NET Core is not yet truly supported. They keep pushing back SignalR3 (which is supposed to be compatible with ASP.NET Core) so I'm trying to work with what is available now. My project is mostly in prototype stage right now anyway.